# Admin style for just one plugin in dashboard

Tags: plugins, functions, admin-css

I'm working on a site with many plugins, two of which are closely related, function-wise, but made by 2 different developers.

Is it possible to style the text from one plugin on the admin end, so that if I'm looking at a user's profile, and there's mention of payment and status (inputs from the plugin in question), that that info gets highlighted in a color, say, yellow - while all other text remains the same old styling from WordPress?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific by showing the HTML for the fields in question? This is totally possible. A good solution will require JavaScript too, so that Field B will be highlighted when Field A has a particular value without first saving the page.

Comment: There's one section in particular that I'd like to highlight for the site owner so that he doesn't keep bugging me about membership not paying.  But there might also be other instances where plugin A inputs text on the admin dashboard.  So I can style the parts I know....'<select name=“membership_level”>…</select>
<span id=“current_level_cost”>Not paying</span> == $0' but what about other parts that the site owner starts complaining about (not yet the object of his attention)?  plugin A doesn't handle payment (but it could which is why the verbiage is there, but unnecessary for us).